# How do you get the current time zone for nsdate using nsdateformatter in objective c or swift

Tags: ios, nsdateformatter

I am downloading a time stamp from a back end server and need to adjust the time which is in GMT to the current time zone for the user so that I can then figure out how much time has elapsed relative to where the user is located. Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Have you tried `NSTimeZone.localTimeZone`?

Comment: What is the format of the time stamp you are downloading?